# How to sort descending order values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following input data:

[image]

I want to get a formula that can sort out descending order values for the factors across the three treatments.

For a particular factor, the formula should return A for six (6) consecutive descending ordered values within the treatment, B for four (4) consecutive descended order values, C for three (3) consecutive descended ordered values, and blank otherwise.

Here is the expected output from the input data sample:

[image]

**Notes**:

1. I'm using office 365, please consider that in your answer
2. I need a formula with drag and drop than doing it manually because in some cases, the factors are up to 100 and more than 70 treatments...

Comment: ¿Are the values always numbers 1 to 6? ¿Always?

Comment: yes, they are always 1 to 6.

Comment: Please help me out, I hooked up

Answer (score 1):

The following formula will return the number of values that appear in consecutively descending order:

```
=LET(
    Order,MMULT(IFERROR(N(C3:H3>D3:H3),0),N(COLUMN(C3:H3)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C3:H3)))),
    Score,UNIQUE(FILTER(Order,Order>0),1,1),
    IF(SUM(ISERROR(Score))=0,COUNT(Score)+2,0)
)
```

So that the resulting table will look like this:

[image: Example Screenshot]

You can then use an `IF()` or `SWITCH()` or `INDEX()` function solution to categorize the numerical scores into the classes 'A', 'B', and 'C'.

Comment: I tried the formula but it is warning me, that ''that function isn't valid'' and highlighting FILTER.

Comment: What type of error shows in the cell that you entered the formula in? #NAME error?

Comment: ''That function isn't valid''

Comment: again, 6,4,3.2.1 are not 5 consecutive descending order values, but 4

Comment: Are you not using Office365? That's the only explanation I can find right now for the "function isn't valid" problem in the context of the `FILTER()` function.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus, 2016

Comment: I'll think about a solution that doesn't use new functions like `FILTER` and `LET` then

Comment: Just for my understanding, would the number series {6,4} be consider consecutively descending or do they have to be seperated by a difference of exactly 1?

Comment: Yes, they have to be separated by a difference of exactly 1

Comment: Please, let's just consider {6,4} to be a consecutively descending order series if getting the one to be separated by exactly 1 can't be obtained. thank you

Comment: Just like the one you obtained in the table above

Answer (score 1):

This would be a partial answer because it cannot be dragged to right.

I've used old functions from Excel 2007 so this should work for you, but I'm pretty sure that with advanced functions this solution can be improved and be dragged to right.

[image]

The formula I've used for Treatment 1 is:

```
=IF(--(CONCATENATE(B2;C2;D2;E2;F2;G2)="654321")>0;"A";IF(O(ISNUMBER(FIND("6543";CONCATENATE(B2;C2;D2;E2;F2;G2)));ISNUMBER(FIND("5432";CONCATENATE(B2;C2;D2;E2;F2;G2)));ISNUMBER(FIND("4321";CONCATENATE(B2;C2;D2;E2;F2;G2))));"B";IF(O(ISNUMBER(FIND("654";CONCATENATE(B3;C3;D3;E3;F3;G3)));ISNUMBER(FIND("543";CONCATENATE(B3;C3;D3;E3;F3;G3)));ISNUMBER(FIND("432";CONCATENATE(B3;C3;D3;E3;F3;G3)));ISNUMBER(FIND("321";CONCATENATE(B3;C3;D3;E3;F3;G3))));"C";"")))
```

My argument separator is the `;` so you may need to replace those with commas